# Make rule obey margins within enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, rules

I am using `\rule` to generate horizontal lines in an `enumerate` environment. The lines should be equal to the width of the `\item` text. This works fine if I just use a single `enumerate` environment. However, when I put these lines in a nested `enumerate` environment, the lines end up overflowing into the margins. Here is my complete code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\hr}{\rule[0.3em]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\newline}

\begin{document}

    \newpage
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm]
        \item \textit{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
        
        \hr
        \lipsum[3][1-5]\\
        \hr
        \lipsum[4][1-5]\\
        \hr
        
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
            
            \hr
            \lipsum[3][1-5]\\
            \hr
            \lipsum[4][1-5]\\
            \hr
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This is what the page looks like when rendered:

[image]

How can I make these lines the proper width? Ideally, I'd also like to maintain just a single `\hr` command, no matter what the level of nesting is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\hr}{\rule[0.3em]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\newline}

\begin{document}

    \newpage
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm]
        \item \textit{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
        
        \hr
        \lipsum[3][1-5]\\
        \hr
        \lipsum[4][1-5]\\
        \hr
        
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textit{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
            
            \hr
            \lipsum[3][1-5]\\
            \hr
            \lipsum[4][1-5]\\
            \hr
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]